# htmlunit input submit returns same page

Tags: forms, authentication, submit, htmlunit

I am trying to do login to my user on a web where login button is an input of type submit. I tried different strategies to fill the login page with my login data and clicking the button, but I ALWAYS get the login page againt
 as a return from click(). I never get the page that appears where you log into using a real browser.

This is my code:

```
String applicationName = "Mozilla";
String applicationVersion = "5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0";
final String userAgent = applicationName + "/" + applicationVersion;
BrowserVersion browserVersion = new BrowserVersion.BrowserVersionBuilder(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_52)
      .setApplicationName(applicationName)
      .setApplicationVersion(applicationVersion)
      .setUserAgent(userAgent)
      .build();

webClient = new WebClient(browserVersion);
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.ALL); 
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.ALL);

webClient.setAjaxController(new com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
webClient.setIncorrectnessListener(new com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListener() {
        @Override public void notify(String arg0, Object arg1) {} 
    });

webClient.setJavaScriptErrorListener(new com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptErrorListener() {
        @Override public void timeoutError(HtmlPage arg0, long arg1, long arg2) {}   
        @Override public void scriptException(final HtmlPage arg0, final com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException arg1) {} 
        @Override public void malformedScriptURL(HtmlPage arg0, String arg1, java.net.MalformedURLException arg2) {}
        @Override public void loadScriptError(HtmlPage arg0, java.net.URL arg1, Exception arg2) {}
    });

webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.SilentCssErrorHandler());
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setDoNotTrackEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setActiveXNative(true);
webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(true);
webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);

webClient.getOptions().setDownloadImages(true);

final int sleepMinSeconds = 1;
final int sleepRandomSeconds = 2;
final long javascriptTimeout = 10000;

System.out.println("Connecting to http://www.milanuncios.com... (" + webClient.getBrowserVersion() + ")");
String loginURL = "https://www.milanuncios.com/mis-anuncios";

System.out.print("    Waiting to avoid being detected as a robot...");
Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random()*sleepRandomSeconds) * 1000);
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(loginURL);
if (!page.asXml().contains("<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"es\" lang=\"es\">")) {
    System.out.println(page.asXml());
    System.out.println("\nDetectado como robot. Saliendo.");
    return;
}
System.out.print("    \nWaiting for Javascript to complete...");
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(javascriptTimeout);
System.out.println("\nOK");

System.out.println("\nDo login...");
System.out.print("    Waiting to avoid being detected as a robot...");
Thread.sleep((sleepMinSeconds + (long)(Math.random()*sleepRandomSeconds)) * 1000);

//<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return estabien()" class="frmMisAnuncios">
HtmlForm loginForm = (HtmlForm)page.getFirstByXPath("//form[@onsubmit='return estabien()']");
((HtmlInput)loginForm.getOneHtmlElementByAttribute("input", "id", "email")).type("my username");
((HtmlInput)loginForm.getOneHtmlElementByAttribute("input", "id", "contra")).type("my password");
HtmlInput btnSend = (HtmlInput)loginForm.getOneHtmlElementByAttribute("input", "class", "submit btnSend");
page = btnSend.click();
System.out.print("    \nWaiting for Javascript to complete...");
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(javascriptTimeout);
System.out.println(page.asXml());
```

Resulting page is always the login page again. Why?

The login form is like this:

```
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return estabien()" class="frmMisAnuncios">
    <input value="0" type=hidden id="recarga">
    <input value="0" type=hidden id="mensajes">
    <div class="sumario">
        <img src="https://static.milanuncios.com/imagenes/userarea/ic_user_avatar.png" width="40" height="40" alt="Acceso a mis anuncios"/> Acceso a mis anuncios
    </div>
    <div class="loginText">
        Email
    </div>
    <div>
        <input value="" type=text id="email" maxlength="50" class="field" tabindex="1" autofocus placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input value="" type=password id="contra" maxlength="4" class="field" tabindex="2" placeholder="ContraseÃ±a">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" value="s" id="rememberme" name="rememberme" class="field" tabindex="3" checked="checked"> No cerrar sesiÃ³n
    </div>
    <div class="fbforgotpasstext">
        <a href="javascript:forgotPassword()" class="effect" id="txtforgotpassword">OlvidÃ© mi contraseÃ±a</a>
    </div>
    <div class="btnEnviarFrm">
        <input type="submit" tabindex="3" class="submit btnSend" value="ENVIAR">
    </div>
</form>
```

And the estabien() Javascript function:

```
function estabien() {
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var contra = document.getElementById('contra').value;
    var recarga = document.getElementById('recarga').value;
    var mensajes = document.getElementById('mensajes').value;
    var rememberme = document.getElementById('rememberme').checked;
    if ((email == '') || (contra == '')) {
        alert('Por favor, proporcione el email y la contraseÃ±a de anuncio.');
        return false;
    }

    var ajax = newAjax();

    ajax.open("POST", '/cmd/');
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    ajax.send("comando=login&email=" + email + '&contra=' + contra + (rememberme ? '&rememberme=s' : ''));
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
            oculta('espera');
            if (ajax.responseText == 'login') {
                if (recarga == 1) {
                    document.location = '/creditos/recargar.php';
                }
                else if (mensajes == 1) {
                    document.location = '/mis-mensajes/';
                }
                else document.location = '/mis-anuncios/';
            }
            else if (ajax.responseText.indexOf('emailantiguo') != -1) {
                alert('ATENCIÃN: El sistema de acceso a los anuncios ha cambiado ahora hay una sola contraseÃ±a para todos ' +
                        'tus anuncios, si no has recibido la nueva contraseÃ±a solicÃ­tala en recordatorio de contraseÃ±as.');
            }
            else if (ajax.responseText.indexOf('emailantiguoenviado') != -1) {
                alert('ATENCIÃN: El sistema de acceso a los anuncios ha cambiado ahora hay una sola contraseÃ±a para todos ' +
                        'tus anuncios, acabamos de enviar a tu correo la nueva clave (si no aparece no olvides mirar en la carpeta de spam o correo no deseado).');
            }
            else if (ajax.responseText.indexOf('malcontra') != -1) {
                alert('El email o la contraseÃ±a no son correctos.\r\n\r\nRecuerda que las contraseÃ±as de milanuncios\r\nson de 4 caracteres de longitud');
            }
            else {
                alert('Se produjo un error, intÃ©ntelo de nuevo ' + ajax.responseText);
                document.location = '/mis-anuncios/';
            }
        }
    };
    ver('espera');
    return false;
}
```

[EDIT]
As additional information, first time login page is loaded, it shows a Javascript error:

```
EcmaError: lineNumber=[1] column=[0] lineSource=[  function () {]name=[TypeError] sourceName=[https://jssdk.pulse.schibsted.com/autoTrackerMilanuncios.min.js] message=[TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined (https://jssdk.pulse.schibsted.com/autoTrackerMilanuncios.min.js#1)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined (https://jssdk.pulse.schibsted.com/autoTrackerMilanuncios.min.js#1)
....
== CALLING JAVASCRIPT ==
  function () {
      o.cb();
  }
```

Whem login page appears after click() this error never appears any more

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your login does some ajax magic and as a result does some kind of redirect to get to the correct result page like this

```
document.location = '/mis-anuncios/';
```

This call replaces the content of the current browser window with the content of the new url. Because ajax is async and the click() method returns the sync result you page variable points to the initial page. You have to reget the content of the current window after the wait.
Try something like this:

```
page = btnSend.click();
System.out.print("    \nWaiting for Javascript to complete...");
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(javascriptTimeout);

// reget the page of the current window to deal with ajax redirects
page.getEnclosingWindow().getTopWindow().getEnclosedPage();

System.out.println(page.asXml());
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hello thanks for your help! I tested the new code and I got same results :-(

Comment: ok, if you like i can try to have a deeper look. But for doing this i need some credentials to reproduce your problem in my local environment. Please send me a sample java class that shows your problem to my private mail (have a look at the HtmlUnit developers list to find the address). And please open an issue in the HtmlUnit bug tracker, otherwise this might get lost in the stack of work.

Comment: What version of HtmlUnit do you use?

Comment: Ok, another try.... please do NOT diable javascript error logging (webClient.setJavaScriptErrorListener). Your problem might be that some javascript fails with HtmlUnit before the request gets sent. Have a look at the log, maybe there is some report about failing javascipt and post the exception. Will have a look

Comment: Hello. Same result, sorry... but I think that the problem is near this. The first time login page is loaded I always get a Javascript error "net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined (https://jssdk.pulse.schibsted.com/autoTrackerMilanuncios.min.js#1)". To be honest, I have the suspect that it is a way to distinguish a robot from a real browser

Comment: Might be, but the lib that throws a javascript error looks like one of these tracker libraries watching you the whole time while surfing the net. Usually they do strange js things but do not stop your page from working if something goes wrong. Do you see more error in the log; maybe from other js files?

Comment: Hello, no more exceptions. Just warnings: "Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'https://static.milanuncios.com/js/image_store.js?versionId=gjDYa0yx7byWwTwbLje8PN4HUIQQDzjK', but got 'text/plain'." and some "Re-synchronized call to ..."

Comment: have updated my suggestion a bit by adding getTopWindow()

Answer (score 0):

With the incredible help of RBRi, who found the simplest version of the program that worked fine, I could find the line on my code that causes the problem:

```
webClient.setAjaxController(new com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
```

Without this line and adding the correct page recovery suggested by RBRi:

```
page = (HtmlPage) page.getEnclosingWindow().getTopWindow().getEnclosedPage();
```

Problem solved!

I hope I can help to someone with this discussion. Bye.